# A program to evenly divide pizzas

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, css

I wrote a program to evenly divide pizzas.
And I tried to stylize it as a console.
I will be grateful for tips on improving my code.

Here is a sample image of the program after a user has entered values:
[image: sample image of output]

```js
$(function(){
 $('.secondQuestion').hide();
 $('#peopleInput').focus();
   
 //Three functions for outputting the result
 const firstOutput = function(a, b){
  if(b>1){
   $('#firstStr').text(a + " people with " + b + " pizzas")
  } else {
   $('#firstStr').text(a + " people with " + b + " pizza")
  }
 } 
 const piece = (a, b) => Math.floor((b * 8) / a);
 const secondOutput = function(a){
  if(a > 1){
   $('#secondStr').text("Each person gets " + a + " pieces of pizza")
  } else {
   $('#secondStr').text("Each person gets " + a + " piece of pizza")
  }
 } 
 const leftover = (a, b) => (b * 8) % a; 
 const thirdOutput = function(a){
  if(a > 1){
   $('#thirdStr').text("There are " + a + " leftover pieces")
  } else {
   $('#thirdStr').text("There is " + a + " leftover pieces")
  }
 }

 //Action after pressing the enter key on the first line
 $('#peopleInput').bind("enterKey", function(e){
  $('.secondQuestion').show();
  $('#pizzaInput').focus();
 });
 $('#peopleInput').keyup(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13){$(this).trigger("enterKey")}
 });

 //Action after pressing the enter key on the second line
 $('#pizzaInput').bind("enterKey", function(e){
  $('#peopleInput').focus();
  const people = $('#peopleInput').val();
  const pizza = $('#pizzaInput').val();
  firstOutput(people, pizza);
  setTimeout(function(){secondOutput(piece(people, pizza)); }, 300);
  setTimeout(function(){thirdOutput(leftover(people, pizza)); }, 600);
 });
 $('#pizzaInput').keyup(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13){$(this).trigger("enterKey")}
 });
});
```

```css
body{
 background: #000;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
}

h2{
 font-weight: normal;
}

.output{
 margin-top: 10px;
}

p{
 margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
input {
 border: none;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
input:focus{
 outline-color: #000;
}

main{
 position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
}
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<header>
 <h2>Pizza Party ></h2>
</header>
<main>
 <div class="firstQuestion">
  <label>How many people?</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="peopleInput" value="" name="" min="0" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');">
 </div>
 <div class="secondQuestion">
  <label >How many pizzas do you have?</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="pizzaInput" value="" name="" min="0" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');">
 </div>
 <div class="output">
  <p id="firstStr"></p>
  <p id="secondStr"></p>
  <p id="thirdStr"></p>
 </div>
</main> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Feedback

I like the style, timing of events, and how the number input spinners are hidden. It really looks like a console application! Plus, pizza is my favorite food!<sup>*</sup>

### Suggestions

#### Cache DOM references

As was mentioned in answers to your other question (like [the retirement calculator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/188533/120114)), any DOM element lookups that happen multiple time should be reduced to a single lookup that is stored in a variable (or a constant using [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)). So in your code, it would be wise to cache `$('#peopleInput');`, `$('#pizzaInput')`, etc...

```
$(function(){
    $('.secondQuestion').hide();
    const peopleInput = $('#peopleInput');
    peopleInput.focus();
    const pizzaInput = $('#pizzaInput');
```

#### Don't repeat yourself

This principle comes to play here with the following blocks:

> ```
> $('#peopleInput').keyup(function(e){
>     if(e.keyCode == 13){$(this).trigger("enterKey")}
> });
> ```

and

> ```
> $('#pizzaInput').keyup(function(e){
>     if(e.keyCode == 13){$(this).trigger("enterKey")}
> });
> ```

These could be combined to a single CSS Selector:

```
$('#peopleInput, #pizzaInput').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){$(this).trigger("enterKey")}
});
```

Since those are the only input elements on the page, it could be simplified to simply `$('input')`, but that might not be a good habit to get into, especially if you go on to larger applications.

#### Naming

Some of the names are misleading. For example: `piece` is actually a function that returns the number of pieces, so something like `pieceDivision` or `getNumerOfPieces` would be more appropriate.

#### Templating

Like I mentioned [in my answer to your question about the retirement calculator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/189006/120114), using templates might allow the code that sets the text to be simplified...

#### Altered Code

With the suggestions above, the code could be modified to be more like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.secondQuestion').hide();
  const peopleInput = $('#peopleInput');
  peopleInput.focus(); //$('#peopleInput').focus();
  const pizzaInput = $('#pizzaInput');

  //Three functions for outputting the result
  const firstOutput = function(a, b) {
    if (b > 1) {
      $('#firstStr').text(a + " people with " + b + " pizzas")
    } else {
      $('#firstStr').text(a + " people with " + b + " pizza")
    }
  }
  const getNumberOfPiecesPerPerson = (a, b) => Math.floor((b * 8) / a);
  const secondOutput = function(a) {
    if (a > 1) {
      $('#secondStr').text("Each person gets " + a + " pieces of pizza")
    } else {
      $('#secondStr').text("Each person gets " + a + " piece of pizza")
    }
  }
  const getNumberOfLeftoverPieces = (a, b) => (b * 8) % a;
  const thirdOutput = function(a) {
    if (a > 1) {
      $('#thirdStr').text("There are " + a + " leftover pieces")
    } else {
      $('#thirdStr').text("There is " + a + " leftover pieces")
    }
  }

  //Action after pressing the enter key on the first line
  peopleInput.bind("enterKey", function(e) {
    $('.secondQuestion').show();
    pizzaInput.focus();
  });
  //combine $('#peopleInput') and $('#pizzaInput') - could also be $('#peopleInput, #pizzaInput')
  $('input').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      $(this).trigger("enterKey")
    }
  });

  //Action after pressing the enter key on the second line
  pizzaInput.bind("enterKey", function(e) {
    peopleInput.focus();
    const numPeople = peopleInput.val();
    const numPizzas = pizzaInput.val();
    firstOutput(numPeople, numPizzas);
    setTimeout(function() {
      secondOutput(getNumberOfPiecesPerPerson(numPeople, numPizzas));
    }, 300);
    setTimeout(function() {
      thirdOutput(getNumberOfLeftoverPieces(numPeople, numPizzas));
    }, 600);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.output {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

input {
  border: none;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

input:focus {
  outline-color: #000;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <header>
    <h2>Pizza Party ></h2>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="firstQuestion">
      <label>How many people?</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="peopleInput" value="" name="" min="0" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');">
    </div>
    <div class="secondQuestion">
      <label>How many pizzas do you have?</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="pizzaInput" value="" name="" min="0" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');">
    </div>
    <div class="output">
      <p id="firstStr"></p>
      <p id="secondStr"></p>
      <p id="thirdStr"></p>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

<sup>*</sup><sub>not that it means the code is worth more, but at least it is interesting!</sub>